# TFS Build 2012 Code Coverage WITHOUT installing VS2012 on bulid machine

Tags: code-coverage

We've moved to TFS 2012 and was under the impression that Code Coverage is separated out and can be obtained by TFS Build without having to install Visual Studio on the build machines.

However, when I enable it in the default build template the following message is generated during the build process:
`Code coverage is enabled for the test run. Install Visual Studio on the following build machine to get code coverage results: XXXXX.`

Do we really still have to install Visual Studio on build machines for basic ALM stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to John Qiao from Microsoft Forum, this is unfortunately still needed.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/8d962eff-f966-4aea-82fc-cb01a79f628a/